# bulkloader.py --dump without authentication

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backup

Is there some way or using the bulkloader.py dump and restore functionality without authentication?
I have tried using:

```
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
```

without the login-parameter, but login still seems to be required.
I still get

```
[ERROR   ] Exception during authentication
```

I struggled with this for 6 hours yesterday, without any solution.

And yes, I have tried GAEBAR.  It failed, however when it got to entities that contain up to 1MB (the maximum pr. entity) Blobs.

So, I am looking to dump (and restore)  for backup-purposes mainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remote_api, which the bulkloader uses, is written to deliberately require authentication, even if you omit the relevant clause in app.yaml. You can override it if you really want, but it's an incredibly bad idea - it would allow any anonymous user to do practically anything they liked to your app!